# change imagebutton during runtime

Tags: android

I have an imagebutton as img1 on toolbar on clicking it displays the linear layout containing imagebuttons as img2, img3, img4 etc.. Now when I click on img2, the button on toolbar that is img1 should change to img2. How I can achieve this?
I tried few different steps onclickListener but it didnt work..

Any help  would be appreciated?

I have searched answer on this, I know how to set one image to another, but I want to set if user selects any button from linear layout.
Thanks

In Activity class I have this piece of code

```
private void showHideAnnotatePanel() {
    ImageButton im = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_pen);
    if (annotatePanel == null) {
        annotatePanel = new AnnotatePanel(this);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
        ll.addView(annotatePanel, 0);
        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.annotateShowing = true;

        if (im != null) {
            im.setImageResource(R.drawable.paintpalette_64_wmblue);
        }
    }
    else if (annotateShowing == false) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        annotateShowing = true;
        if (im != null) {
            im.setImageResource(R.drawable.paintpalette_64_wmblue);
        }
    }
    else {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        annotateShowing = false;
        if (im != null) {
            im.setImageResource(R.drawable.brush_icon_selector);
        }
    }
}

the new_annotate_screen.xml file is



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#323232"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="#323232"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col_one"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!--  -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_red_col"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="#ff0000" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_green_col"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="#00ff00" />
       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_blue_col"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="#0000ff" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_yellow_col"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="#ffff00" />


 </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you use options menu? or a custom toolbar that has imageview

Comment: @seyedJafari I used custom toolbar which contains imagebutton

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: @seyedJafari I added the code

Answer (score 0):

```
//considering R.drawable.paintpalette_64_wmblue is the img2
    img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.paintpalette_64_wmblue);
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually, its not giving any error in logcat it just dont set that image and I have the layout inflated for that image button in another class which handle the listener of suppose img2, So how do I set there? I tried getter/setter didnt work